# How to check if a sequence is graphic?( multiple edges are allowd but loops are disallowed)

Tags: graph-theory

How to check if a sequence is graphic?( multiple edges are allowed but loops are disallowed)
If multiple edges are also disallowed, the problem can be solved by Havel–Hakimi algorithm.
But if multiple edges are allowed, how to solve it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence $d_1 \ge d_2 \ge \dots \ge d_n$ is clearly not "multigraphic" if $d_1 > d_2 + d_3 + \dots + d_n$, since the first vertex wants more edges out of it than all the others combined.

On the other hand, if no degree is greater than the sum of all the others, then this continues to be true of we decrease $d_1$ and $d_2$ (the two largest degrees) by $1$. So we can (inductively) construct the multigraph with degree sequence $(d_1-1, d_2-1, d_3, \dots, d_n)$ then add an edge between vertices $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Your reply helps me a lot! Thank you very much!